# httphandler in asp.net handler.ashx file not triggered for *.aspx file

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, httphandler

I have an old website based on asp.net webform. I need to change the url to friendly using the same site and also keep support for old url.

For this i thought of using HTTP Handler so that i can intercept the old url and redirect them to correct page with new url

**example**

`old url: /news.aspx?newsID=10`

`new url: /news/10/title-of-the-news`

Using handler file `URLHandler.ashx` i want to redirect page to right page or recreate the new url.

what i did so far

1. create `URLHandler.ashx`  wrote logic to redirect to new url or let us say i created the new URL and redirected the page
2. registered the handler in we.config

This is not working for me when i run `/news.aspx?newsID=10` first it should execute handler file and the redirect to the page based on the url.

I am not sure if i have done something wrong.

`web.config`

```
  <system.webServer>
    <!-- Un Comment This Part on web server     Un Comment This Part on web server -->
    <handlers>
      <add name="url-handler" verb="*" path="*.aspx"  type="URLHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      <add name="ChartImg" path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </handlers>

    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  </system.webServer>
```

SAMPLE Handler file code

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="URLHandler" %>

using System;
using System.Web;

public class URLHandler : IHttpHandler {

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
       // context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        //context.Response.Write("Hello World");
        HttpResponse r = context.Response;

        r.Write(context.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you need a `r.End()` to end the response processing? Not sure though.

Comment: Easier solution is just  intercepting the request in Global.asax Application_BeginRequest and rewriting the path using Context.RewritePath https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.rewritepath(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I am not sure, while debugging it is not entering the `URLHandler.ashx` file

Comment: @Mathew, I have done exactly in one of the projects i am checking url in begin request and then handling the request. But i am not sure why this is not working or what is the recommended way of doing it. Taken into consideration it is webform 4.0 & IIS 7.5

Answer (score 1):

Place the code in a `.cs` file. I've reproduced your project (with the code in an `.ashx` file) and received the following error:

> **Could not load type 'URLHandler'.**
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Having the code in a `.cs` file in `App_Code` resulted in it working as you expected. I *suspect* that this is something to do with the fact that code inside `.ashx` files gets compiled slightly differently to account for the fact that it's responding to a specific URL (`URLHandler.ashx`) as it's a physical file, rather than being a class that's referenced from `web.config` which may be sufficient to mangle the name/location of the type so IIS can't find it when referenced in config.

Comment: how to you define path in webconfig file

Comment: I am getting following error `URLHandler does not implement IHttpHandlerFactory or IHttpHandler.`

Comment: @Learning, you don't specify a **path** to the handler in the web.config file. You specify the type of the handler in the **type** attribute, which is exactly what you've done. You do need to ensure that you specify the type correctly though (see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d6sws33(v=vs.71).aspx). If you're getting the error "URLHandler does not implement", then the type it's resolving doesn't implement IHttpHandler. Do you have more than one type called "URLHandler" in your project?

Comment: @mathew, I defined it like this in my `web.config` file `<add name="url-handler" verb="*" path="*.aspx"  type="URLHandler.cs" resourceType="Unspecified" />`. No i dont  have any other handler. I also removed URLHandler.ashx file from project but i am still getting the error

Comment: @Learning, read the documentation I linked to so you understand what should be in the "type" attribute there. What you've got is wrong. `type="URLHandler"` *might* work, but following the documentation and seeing the example will ensure that it does **and** that you understand it =)